# How do I keep the spring-security-core login screen when using the spring-security-ui plugin

Tags: grails, grails-spring-security

I am migrating a grails app from 2.3.4 to 3.3.9. I created a new app and am bringing in the code piece by piece. I have the "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3" dependency and "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.1.2" because I want the user/role management screens.

From my investigation both plugins include login/auth.gsp, and it seems my app is using ui instead of core, but this is not how my 2.3.4 app behaved using ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2" and ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1". Is there some way to configure or force the app to use login/auth.gsp from core? If not, can I just copy the one I want into my local views folder? Would there be any compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

I copied https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/3.2.x/grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp into my views folder, and it seems to work fine and give me the results I want. There seem to be no obvious compatibility issues.